# Is there only one instance of c++11 singleton from static library

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton

I use a class which has a singleton get method which returns a static local library. This is threadsafe in C++1. When I compile this class as a static library and use this library in two different shared libraries: Is there only one instance of the singleton when linking these two shared libraries with an application?

Comment: The best general advice I can give is: Don't use the _Singleton Pattern_ at all.

Comment: I know that but I see no other way than using it for sharing configuration parameters across the whole app without initializing every class with the configuration class.

Comment: Invert the design principle. Don't access configuration parameters from trhoughout the whole system, but configure the classes at time of their creation with the relevant configuration values. Having a properly designed and implemented _Factory Pattern_ is useful for this.

Comment: Please, please, please! Don't use singletons. They are an anti-pattern, glorified global variables, increase coupling in your code, will cause pain when they are destroyed after `main`, will cause pain when they end up depending on construction order of other singletons, will cause immense pain when used from multiple threads. Just say NO! Getting rid of singletons in my work life is killing sooo many bugs.

Comment: "returns a static local library"...?

Comment: Ok no more singletons but factory patterns aren't appropriate for every use. There seems to be no elegant way at all.

Comment: If you wanted a way to get a true singleton across DLLs, I have it. But that's not the question you asked. Nor did you ask "What's the best way of distributing configuration values throughout a program without using singletons?" But if you did, the same people telling you not to use singletons would close the question as "opinion based".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each DLL will get its own copy of the singleton in Windows. I've heard it's different in Linux but I have no direct experience there.

When the linker is invoked to create the shared library, it will copy any code it needs out of any static libraries - including the static variables defined in that code. Each shared library that is created will get a different copy of the code and variables.